# CMake: detect "--config Release" in if condition

Tags: cmake, build, release

I want to build a target only in release mode, so i need a 'if(RELEASE)' or something.
I found

```
if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE EQUAL "RELEASE")
```

but it doesnt work, because i build with the following command

```
cmake --build . --config Release
```

which apparently doesnt set CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.

What's the correct way to detect Release vs Debug build with modern cmake?

(I cant use generator expressions because i need an actual if() )

Comment: Do not use `--config` at _build stage_ and use `-D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` at _configuration stage_.

Comment: hm, i was told  "cmake .." + "cmake --build . --config Release|Debug" is  best practice in modern cmake. is  that wrong?

Comment: That depends on if you're using multi generator or single generator. Anyway, you can't go back in time - `if()` in CMake is executed at configuration stage, so if you want `if()` then you have to specify build type at configure stage.

Comment: "(I cant use generator expressions because i need an actual if() )" - I don't think that's true. Branching off the config type is pretty much always invalid anyway, thanks to how multi-config generators work.

Comment: I have looked into it more now. It seems that under windows -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE doesnt work at all. It's simply not considered. only --config works, which is a multigen of the underlying msvc buildsystem. 
So the question is, how can I build a subtarget only for a specific build-config when using multi-generators?